# upload multiple images using laravel API : with polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, api, polymorphism

I'm building an API with Laravel 8 and I have posts and images table with polymorphic relation

So I want to upload multiple images and I'm doing it in postman, And when I upload images and enter posts fields with values, like this:

[image]

as you can see, I have an error in my foreach($files as $file)

`ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

(In headers part Content-Type has multipart/form-data value )

So I think my problem is in store() method in postController ,

The codes :

post tables :

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->string('video')->nullable();
            $table->string('study_time');
            $table->integer('likes')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->nullable()->comment('status is 1 when a post is active and it is 0 otherwise.')->nullable();
            $table->text('tags')->nullable();


            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
         });
```

and my image table :

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('imageable_id');
            $table->string('imageable_type');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and the post model :

```
.
.
.
.
 public function image(){
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class , 'imageable');
    }
```

and my image model :

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'url'
    ];

    public function imageable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

and my store() method in postController :

```
public function store(Request $request )
    {

        $post = new Post;
        $post->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        $post->title = $request->get('title');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->study_time = $request->get('study_time');
        $post->tags = $request->get('tags');
        $post->user_id = JWTAuth::user()->id;
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);
        $post->tag($tags);

        $allowedfileExtension=['pdf','jpg','png'];
        $files = $request->file('fileName');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);
            if($check) {
                foreach($request->fileName as $mediaFiles) {

                    $url = $mediaFiles->store('public/images');

                    //store image file into directory and db
                    $image = new Image();
                    $image->url = $url;
                }
            }
            else {
                return response()->json(['invalid_file_format'], 422);
            }
        }


        $post->image()->save($image);
        $post->save();

        return response()->json($post , 201);
    }
```

thank you for your help :}

Answer (score 1):

```php
$files = $request->file('fileName');
```

... is returning null in your case, done you are not posting `fileName`, you use `url`.

If you would have validated your incoming data you would have received a validation errors 6 because of this. So: always validate incoming d data. Not only to catch errors like this, also b for security reasons.

Comment: thank you .. i changed it .. but i have an error again .. the `$image` that i use in my code , is  Undefined variable ,Why am I getting this error? i defined it in foreach

Comment: This seems incorrect: `foreach($request->fileName as $mediaFiles) {`. You seem to perform the same foreach inside a foreach. Your `$image` is probably never even created.

Comment: yes i dd() $image it didn't created. and i don't know how to change my code :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if ($this->getErrorIfAny($request->all(), $this->ruls)) {
        return $this->getErrorIfAny($request->all(), $this->ruls);
    }

    if (!$request->hasFile('image_url')) {
        return response($this->getResponseFail(trans('my_keywords.uploadFileNotFound'), false), 400);
    }

    $allowedfileExtension = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'];

    $files = $request->file('image_url');

    $number_photos_upload = count($files);

    $pictures_available_upload = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $extension = $files[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);

        if ($check) {
            $pictures_available_upload[$i] = $files[$i];
        }
    }

    $number_images_success_uploded = 0;

    $images_urls = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($pictures_available_upload); $i++) {

        $image = $pictures_available_upload[$i];

        $path = config('paths.storage_path') .
            $image->store(config('paths.store_image_path'), 'public');

        //store image file into directory and db
        $store_images = new StoreImages();
        $store_images['store_id'] = $request['store_id'];
        $store_images['image_url'] = $path;
        $result = $store_images->save();
        if ($result) {
            $images_urls[$i] = $path;
            $number_images_success_uploded = $number_images_success_uploded + 1;
        }
    }

    if ($number_images_success_uploded == 0) {
        return response($this->getResponseFail(trans('my_keywords.invalidFileFormat'), false), 422);
    } else {
        $data = [
            'store_id' => (int) $request['store_id'],
            'number_photos_upload' => $number_photos_upload,
            'number_images_success_uploded' => $number_images_success_uploded,
            'images' => $images_urls,
        ];
        return response($this->getResponse(__('my_keywords.operationSuccessfully'), true, $data), 200);
    }
}
```